# Exporting data from SQL Developer only pulls half of the query output - is there a preference for increasing this?

Tags: excel, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm on version 19.2.1.247 of SQL Developer and ran a script that returned 80,000 records. I exported to Excel (Right click data grid, select 'Export', select Excel 2003+ for the format) and the Excel sheet contained only 40,000 records. I've used SQL Developer for many years but this is the first I've noticed this issue.

I repeated a couple of times with the same query, trying different export formats, and no luck. I tried a different query and the same thing happened - the query itself returned 60,000 records but after exporting to Excel, the file contained only 30,000 records.

I will add that I looked for something under the Tools -> Preferences menu but didn't see anything. The closest was under Tools-> Preferences -> Export -> Worksheet. There are two options there - 'Max rows to print in a script' and 'Max lines in script output.' Both of those had values and I deleted those values so there are no limits. Still, when I exported my data, the Excel sheet contained only half of the records that were retrieved in the output in SQL Developer.

Has anybody run into this and/or is there a preference that can be set to increase the number of records exported to Excel?

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: You're probably hitting a bug, upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Remove the limit of rows fetched or refresh data before you export

Comment: Thank you - where can I do that? I don't see any place to adjust that option.